# Always have the ring of the tensor product below the \otimes

Tags: macros, math-operators

I would rather have always have my tensor product look like `$A\underset{R}{\otimes}B$` but still write `$A\otimes_R B$`. Is there a way to make this happen by some command in the preamble? (it's ok if it only works in display mode)

Comment: `\bigotimes` is a symbol that takes limits, so use that instead.

Comment: One would use that in the sense of `\sum` for addition. In math sometimes you have to specify over which ring one does the tensor product (of just two modules).

Comment: An idea I just had would be something like `\renewcommand{\tensor}{\ensuremath\otimes\limits}` but it does not work because `\otimes` is not a math operator.

Comment: you could then try `\mathop{\opotimes}{$\otimes$}` (i've forgotten which code says this takes limits, and i'm not sure this syntax is exactly correct either, but it's in the right direction).  or `\DeclareMathOperator` from `amsmath`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Perhaps you like the ring to go below the tensor product symbol, but typography doesn't. Here's why:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tens}[1]{%
  \mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\limits_{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, but note that
it will have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simple change will make what you perhaps prefer, but I'm not sure to like it very much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tens}[1]{%
  \mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\displaylimits_{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.
\[
M\tens{R}N
\]
Here is a tensor product $M\tens{R}N$, note that
it won't have a very bad influence on the spacing of
lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can have `\tens` work with the usual syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tens}{t_}
 {%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\tensop}
   {\otimes}%
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\tensop}{m}
 {%
  \mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\displaylimits_{#1}}%
 }

\begin{document}
In line we have $M\tens N=M\tens_{R}N$, but displayed we have
\[
M\tens N=M\tens_{R}N
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more LaTeX3 savvy implementation, using the (not so much) experimental `e` argument specifier (*embellishment*):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\tens}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathbin{\mathop{\otimes}\displaylimits
    \IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}
    \IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}
In line we have $M\tens N=M\tens_{R}N$, but displayed we have
\[
M\tens N=M\tens_{R}N
\]
For a derived functor $M\tens^{L}N=M\tens_{R}^{L}N$ or
\[
M\tens^{L}N=M\tens_{R}^{L}N
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PeterPatzt I'll tell you that in my young years as a LaTeX user I had to use `\otimes` many times and I too wanted the ring below it; but I realized that it's not so nice, after all.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty impressive stuff (to me)!
Thanks alot. (I cannot up your answer twice :( )

Comment: This is awesome! Is it possible to modify your xparse code to have superscripts show up above the tensor as well? I often use tensor products with an L above them (for left derived functor i.e. Tor).

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Added; however, keep in mind that the feature is experimental, so it might change in the future. I believe it's unlikely it disappears, though.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ The `e` argument type has undergone a breaking change, I accordingly fixed the implementation.

Comment: I wasn't looking for this answer, but as soon as I read your code it's impossible to feel that it will be useful in the future. Thank you!